# How to set the position and size (programmatically) for the main window?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I'm using the newest default project for OS X (10.11, Xcode 7.0). It uses storyboards and the hierarchy is as follows:

```
Window Controller -> View Controller
```

I want to set the initial position and frame size for the window. Obviously the user can change that, but I want it to start with some defaults. I've tried subclassing `NSWindowController`, but that has no effect.

```
  class WindowController: NSWindowController {

     override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        guard let window = window else {
           return
        }

        let windowOriginPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let windowSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 400)
        window.setFrame(NSRect(origin: windowOriginPoint, size: windowSize), display: true)

        print("windowDidLoad")
     }

  }
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Have you connected the window controller to your storyboard?

Comment: By "connected", do you mean have I set the class name in the attributes inspector to the name of my class? I have.

Comment: I will take a deeper look into this

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I solved it by moving the `setFrame` code inside `windowDidBecomeMain` instead of `windowDidLoad`; there is a bad side effect if the window has been moved manually and is reselected to become main: window jumps when dragged and immediately returns to the right position. To avoid it, I used a patch: In the `windowController`, I declare a

```
private var firstAppearance = true;
```

In the `windowDidBecomeMain` I do the setFrame only on `firstAppearance`; then I set `firstAppearance` to false.